# Python Pandas SUMIF excel equivalent

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I can't figure out how to achieve a certain task in my python script.

I have a dataframe that contains media coverage for a specific topic. One of my columns names the author of the specific article for example...

[image]

I am trying to create a pivot table to show the total count for each journalist in the column like so

```
datajournalist = company1_topline.pivot_table(index='AuthorUsername', values='ContentID', aggfunc= np.count_nonzero )
```

which would give me something like

```
AuthorUsername                                                 count_nonzero
Aaron Mehta                                                      1              
Aamer Madhani                                                    1               
Aamer Madhani ; Ben Fox                                          1
```

What I am looking for is a way to have the pivot table also count the names that appear in multiple value cells, to get a true count of each author. So for example the row that has "Aamer Madhani ; Ben Fox" would also count towards the count for just "Aamer Madhani" so the row for just "Aamer Madhani" would have a count of 2 instead of 1 etc.... Is there a way to do this? In excel this can be achieved with a SUMIF, but I do not know how to do this with Python/Pandas.

Desired output

```
AuthorUsername                                                 count_nonzero
Aaron Mehta                                                      1              
Aamer Madhani                                                    2               
Aamer Madhani ; Ben Fox                                          1
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your DataFrame having the `AuthorUsername` column like this:

```
            AuthorUsername
0              Aaron Mehta
1            Aamer Madhani
2  Aamer Madhani ; Ben Fox
```

You can do:

```
import collections

# Remove leading and trailing spaces (if any).
df['AuthorUsername'] = df['AuthorUsername'].str.strip()

# Get unique authors and their counts.
authors_counts = collections.Counter(df['AuthorUsername'].str.split('\s*;\s*').sum())

# Add to new column.
real_counts = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1, authors_counts)
df['count_nonzero'] = [real_counts[a] for a in df['AuthorUsername']]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
            AuthorUsername  count_nonzero
0              Aaron Mehta              1
1            Aamer Madhani              2
2  Aamer Madhani ; Ben Fox              1
```

### Edit after comments - sum more metrics:

After the comments, here is a more versatile version to also sum the `Metrics` column, and potentially others.

Input dataframe:

```
            AuthorUsername  Metrics
0              Aaron Mehta      1.3
1            Aamer Madhani      2.0
2  Aamer Madhani ; Ben Fox      0.5
```

Code:

```
df['AuthorUsername'] = df['AuthorUsername'].str.strip()
df['single_authors'] = df['AuthorUsername'].str.split('\s*;\s*')

df['count_nonzero'] = 1
single_metrics = df.explode('single_authors').groupby('single_authors').sum()
multiple_metrics = df[df['single_authors'].map(len) > 1].groupby('AuthorUsername').sum()

all_metrics = pd.concat([single_metrics, multiple_metrics]).rename_axis('AuthorUsername').reset_index()

df = df.drop(columns=['Metrics', 'count_nonzero', 'single_authors']).merge(all_metrics, how='left', on='AuthorUsername')

print(df)
```

Result:

```
            AuthorUsername  Metrics  count_nonzero
0              Aaron Mehta      1.3              1
1            Aamer Madhani      2.5              2
2  Aamer Madhani ; Ben Fox      0.5              1
```

Comment: Thanks, works beautifully. There's one last step I want to implement into the new dataframe related to the author count above, after playing around with it for a few hours I find myself stuck again. There's another column in my starting dataframe that contains floating point numbers titled "Metrics". This column represents the reach of the website the author published on. How can I find the true count of the Metrics column for each individual author?  like what was done above to find the count of each author.

Comment: @frito I see, I edited my answer with the solution. Let me know if I understood correctly!

Comment: You are a legend. Exactly what I needed to accomplish. Thank you.